# Clear sort, event listener button js

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

I want to create a button that resets all the filters on the page. Ale EventListery.

I have a few radio buttons. I have a list of items that can be segregated by price, size and color (click on the radio button).

When I am clicking on the button (reset button), I want the filter remove and the items return to their position before filtering.

This is my code

```
function stop() {
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice--radio')).map(x => x.removeEventListener("click", sortNumber));
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.choice--radio')).map(x => x.checked = false);
}

clear.addEventListener('click', stop);
```

HTML code

```
<ul class="sort__options">
        <li>
          <input class="choice choice--radio" name="sort" type="radio" id="sort-title">
          <label class="choice__label" for="sort-title">title</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="choice choice--radio" name="sort" type="radio" id="sort-subscribers">
          <label class="choice__label" for="sort-subscribers">subscribers</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="choice choice--radio" name="sort" type="radio" id="sort-videos">
          <label class="choice__label" for="sort-videos">videos</label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input class="choice choice--radio" name="sort" type="radio" id="sort-views">
          <label class="choice__label" for="sort-views">views</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

I am removing the checked attribute. But the elements do not return to their orginal position, they are in the order that they have sorted this event.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: **Aside note:** The function `map` is totally unnecessary, use the function `forEach` instead.

Comment: @Due, can you provide code for `.choice--radio` element?

Comment: There are a few circumstances and several possibilities that can only be assessed if the HTML and the sorting function is posted. Refer to how to make a [mcve].

Comment: @ЧебаковДмитрий  I added HTML code

Comment: @zer00ne I added HTML code

Comment: Thanks @Doe I'll need the sorting function since I cannot ascertain the nature of your issue:  *"But the elements do not return to their original position, they are in the order that they have sorted this event."*

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `Form reset()` Method Which is

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Try out the following:

```
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Reset Button">
```

Then go ahead and declare the script as:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
```

Please try that out.